# Angular 2 webpack dev server response headers

Tags: angularjs, webpack, response, email-headers

I am currently studying angular 2 using cli with webpack dev server. I am trying to implement authentication using JWT but the problem is, in development mode using webpack dev server, i cannot get the response headers that i need. When i build it and deploy it in backend server(Spring rest) i am able to get the response headers. Can you please help me solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: The dev server only serves static assets. How could you get a response to an authentication request from this dev server? You must have your server hosting the REST services up and running to test the application.

Comment: i did, my rest service is up and running. I am only using the dev server for development purpose. I am able to get the response body but not the headers.